# trying to debug c++ code from vscode on MacOS

Tags: visual-studio-code, c++

I am trying to debug c++17 code from VSCode on MacOS, I able to build it through VSCode command line but when I try to build debug it get this error :

[image: error]

How to configure launch and task JSON files in VSCode to build C++17 code?
and also I want to compile co-routine code of C++20. How can the same build in VSCode?

Comment: could build C++17 on MacOS by adding clang compiler in launch.json file in vscode, but still not able to build coroutine code vscode, I tried including <experimental/coroutine> but didn't work. it gives error: use of undeclared identifier 'co_await'

Answer (score 1):

Install an IDE that supports C++. Visual Studio Code is a full featured code editor, but it is not an IDE like Visual Studio. Any commonly used IDE that supports C++ will do. XCode is a pretty neat IDE with a built in C++ compiler so you can write C++, compile with a click and run.

Comment: compilation happens through vscode when installs c++ plugin but how to use coroutine code, I tried experimental/coroutine but that is not compiling.

Comment: Precarious, tottering experimental infrastructure is required in VSCode, but not required in XCode in MacOS.

Answer (score 0):

I could build C++17 code in VSCODE on MacOS, with below config:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "clang++ build active file",
            "command": "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-std=c++17",
                "--debug",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: though still not found how to build coroutine as not sure how to include C++20 as compile time option.

Answer (score 0):

To build and debug C++ code in VSCode on macOS, you should follow [this tutorial](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-clang-mac)

Your c_cpp_properties.json (within the .vscode folder in your project folder) should then look like this (replace YOURUSERNAME by your macOS username):

```
{
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Mac",
        "includePath": [
            "${workspaceFolder}/**",
            "/Users/YOURUSERNAME/bin/CPP_Libraries/Eigen/Eigen/**"
        ],
        "defines": [],
        "macFrameworkPath": ["/System/Library/Frameworks",
            "/Library/Frameworks"],
        "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/clang",
        "cStandard": "c11",
        "cppStandard": "c++17",
        "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64"
    }
],
"version": 4
```

}